# Is it safe to host javascript files for the users apps?

Tags: javascript, security, open-source, code-injection

we have online site (application). we are letting developers / opensource community to easily embed there plugins / applications easily with javascript code.

we were wondering, should we host the file on our domain and server or should we let developers host there own files and just include there files in the site.

which method do you think it will be safe to go with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing arbitrary JavaScript in pages on your domain is dangerous. It will get full access to the data on your site (that is available to the user accessing the page) no matter where it is hosted.

If you host it yourself you can audit it (manually or automatically) before you publish it.

If you allow third parties to host it, they can change it at any time.

Comment: yes we are allowing them to access data on the site. which is our data, not user data. but we were wondering which way would be safer.. to host our self or let them host it? what do you prefer?

Comment: That isn't obvious from the last two paragraphs of the answer? It is safer in the place where you can audit it and you control when it can be changed.